# Как найти максимальное количество подряд идущих одинаковых элементов массива? JAVA

Tags: java

Получилось, только выводить число массива, который повторяется.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// write your code here
    int[] numbers = new int[5];
    Scanner inn = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean b = true;
    int temp = -1;
    System.out.println("Введите 5 элементов массива");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = inn.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.print("\nСумма повторяющихся элементов массивов: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (!b) {
            System.out.print(temp + " ");
        }

        b = true;
        temp = numbers[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
            if (i != j && temp == numbers[j] && numbers[j] != -2) {
                b = false;
                numbers[j] = -2;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: сравнивать попарно элементы и считать повторяющиеся. Или в чем проблема?

Comment: Да, Как это сделать?

Comment: Что сделать? Сравнение? Вон, в коде есть, не надо делать вид, что не знаете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант 1:

Во-первых, заводите счётчик для максимального числа соседних повторов.

Затем, для каждого *i*-го числа заводите текущий счётчик повторов, считаете количество равных ему *последующих* чисел во вложенном цикле (т.е. начиная от `j = i + 1`, не забывая проверять выход `j` за верхнюю границу массива) и увеличиваете текущий счётчик и `i`.

После окончания вложенного цикла, обновляете при необходимости максимум повторов.

Реализация в коде не приводится в педагогических целях.

---

Вариант 2 (без вложенного цикла):

- Завести счетчики `count`, `maxCount` вне цикла, инициализировать оба `0`.
- Внутри цикла: для первого элемента или если текущий элемент равен предыдущему, инкрементировать `count`; сразу же при необходимости обновить `maxCount` (запомнить размер самой длинной последовательности)
- Иначе сбросить `count` в `1`.
- По окончании цикла вывести/вернуть значение, накопленное в `maxCount`.

Comment: вложенный цикл-то зачем? Одного достаточно

Comment: @Эникейщик, да, описал вариант без вложенного цикла.